# não consigo instalar a Biblioteca ChatterBot

Tags: python

Quando tento instalar essa biblioteca da erro, e não soube identificar qual seria esse erro. mas já tentei outras bibliotecas e instala normalmente. em certa parte do erro fala que requer o Microsoft visual C++ 14 ou superior, eu já tenho instalado ele, e uso o Pycharm para escrever os códigos. segue o erro:
PS C:\Users\Oem> pip install chatterbot
Collecting chatterbot
Using cached ChatterBot-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting pint>=0.8.1
Using cached Pint-0.18-py2.py3-none-any.whl (209 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.3,>=1.2
Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.2.19-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
Collecting mathparse<0.2,>=0.1
Using cached mathparse-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (7.2 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<5.2,>=5.1
Using cached PyYAML-5.1.2.tar.gz (265 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\users\oem\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from chatterbot) (2021.3)
Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [79 lines of output]
Collecting setuptools
Using cached setuptools-60.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting wheel<0.33.0,>0.32.0
Using cached wheel-0.32.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting Cython
Using cached Cython-0.29.27-py2.py3-none-any.whl (983 kB)
Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
Using cached cymem-2.0.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (36 kB)
Collecting preshed<2.1.0,>=2.0.1
Using cached preshed-2.0.1.tar.gz (113 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
Using cached murmurhash-1.0.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (21 kB)
Collecting thinc<7.1.0,>=7.0.8
Using cached thinc-7.0.8.tar.gz (1.9 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting blis<0.3.0,>=0.2.1
Using cached blis-0.2.4.tar.gz (1.5 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.0.9
Using cached wasabi-0.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting srsly<1.1.0,>=0.0.6
Using cached srsly-1.0.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (178 kB)
Collecting numpy>=1.7.0
Using cached numpy-1.22.2-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl (14.7 MB)
Collecting plac<1.0.0,>=0.9.6
Using cached plac-0.9.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.10.0
Using cached tqdm-4.62.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting colorama
Using cached colorama-0.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for preshed, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for thinc, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for blis, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: wasabi, srsly, plac, murmurhash, cymem, wheel, setuptools, preshed, numpy, Cython, colorama, tqdm, blis, thinc
Running setup.py install for preshed: started
Running setup.py install for preshed: finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

```
    Running setup.py install for preshed did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1

    [22 lines of output]
    WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_counter.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_hashing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\test_pop.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed\tests
    copying preshed\counter.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\maps.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\counter.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\maps.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    copying preshed\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\preshed
    running build_ext
    building 'preshed.maps' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: legacy-install-failure

  Encountered error while trying to install package.

  preshed

  note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
  hint: See above for output from the failure.
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

Answer (score 0):

Cara tive o mesmo problema então tentei instalar clonando do gitHub e apareceu esse erro: "ERROR: Package 'chatterbot' requires a different Python: 3.10.2 not in '<=3.8,>=3.4'". Me parece que só roda nas versões 3.8 e 3.4 e a minha era a 3.10.2

baixa o python 3.8 : https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/
e quando for criar um novo projeto no pycharm escolhe o interpretador do 3.8 (na hora da instalação copia o path) que vai funcionar (testei aqui!)

fonte: Documentação chatterbot https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/setup.html
[image: Seleciona o interpretador e gg]

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).